# Directive not working. Not sure how to debug

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am in the process of implementing a jQuery library using an Angular directive. But I presume that the HTML element is not being matched with the directive on page load.

I've been following Dan Wahlin's [guide on how to use directives](https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-2-isolate-scope).

Here is my directive implementation:

```
var TopicIsotope = function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log("firing");
            $(element).isotope({
                itemSelector: '.grid-topic',
                masonry: {
                    // use outer width of grid-sizer for columnWidth
                    columnWidth: '.grid-topic-sizer'
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

TopicIsotope.$inject = [];
```

Here is the line where I attach it to the module:

```
.directive('topicIsotope', TopicIsotope);
```

Here is how I am trying to invoke the directive in the HTML:

```
<topic-isotope>
    <div class="grid-topic-sizer"></div>
    <div class="grid-topic" ng-repeat="topic in topics">
        <p ng-bind="topic.name"></p>
    </div>
</topic-isotope>
```

`ng-repeat` is working. But the directive isn't working at all and I'm not sure how to debug since I get no error in the console.

Answer (score 0):

The directive appears to call the `link` function before the `ng-repeat` has time to render the `.grid-topic` elements inside it.
This means that `$(element).isotope()` doesn't find any `.grid-topic`s when it's initialized.

I've made a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/czfFlo7jSWvOehBlQwOd) showing that there are 0 `.grid-topic` elements when initializing `isotope`.

With this being said, I don't have a simple solution for your problem.
Maybe you can try using a template for your directive.

Comment: I'm not even getting the `console.log()` message in my link function, though. The directive is bound to the angular app.

Comment: Okay, I think the problem is in the normalization phase. When I bind it using the string name `TopicIsotope`, it doesn't work. But `topicIsotope` triggers the console.log().

Comment: Even if you mange to get the directive to work with ng-repeat at initialization, there might be another problem with how isotope will work when adding new elements to the list. You will either have to reinitialize isotope or append the new element to those tracked by isotope everytime you add a new element to the list.

Comment: if you add a console.log() to @Cosmin Bacanu's plnkr the console.log works fine for me.